# HP printer update failing

Tags: windows, windows-10, printer

There used to be an HP printer on my friend's computer. When it died they purchased and installed a new printer (not HP) which is working correctly. They also uninstalled the HP printer. As it turns out Windows update has been failing everyday for months trying to update the old HP printer.

Here's what I've checked.

1. Under the printers in the control panel there is no HP printer listed. Just the new printer.
2. Under Uninstall a program there is no HP anything listed.
3. I found and disabled the HP service running. It stays disabled after restarts, but this issue is still there.
4. There are no HP processes running under startup processes. Nothing to disable there.

[image: HP Update failing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about this for a while and realized I forgot about the device manager. In the device manager under printers there was the current printer and an unknown device. I uninstalled the unknown device and that solved the problem.